# ArrayList running out of memory

Tags: java, android

I must write a method that:

1. If the size is even ---->> switch the order of the first two values then switch the order of the next two values, etc

   2. If the size is odd ---->> do the same as above but DON't touch the last element.
   3. Doesn't have to return anything (void)

SO FAR, THIS IS WHAT I HAVE WRITTEN AND IT THROWS AN EXCEPTION EVERY TIME (RUNNING OUT OF MEMORY)

```
public static void switchPairs(ArrayList<String> al){
    //temporary object definition
    String temp = null;
    //size is even
    if(al.size() %2==0){        
        //loop through the entire arraylist
        for(int i=0; i<al.size()-1; i++){
            //get the n+1 element and assign it to a temp variable
             temp=al.get(i+1);  
              //assign the n+1 element to the n position
                al.add(i, temp);                            
        }
     } else {  //size is odd    
            //loop through the entire arraylist
    }
    System.out.println("After switching pairs.");
    System.out.println(al);
}
```

OUTPUT:

PLEASE HELP ME FOLKS!
THANK YOU!

Comment: did you got it solved?

Answer (score 1):

You should update existing ArrayList elements with the **set method**. By adding to the ArrayList you are increasing its size so your loop never terminates since the end condition is for **i** to be equal to the size minus one. This condition is never met so your collection keeps growing until you run out of memory.

```
for(int i=0; i<al.size()-1; i++){
  tmp = al.get(i+1);
  al.set(i+1,al.get(i));     
  al.set(i, tmp) //assign the n+1 element to the n position
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem here is that you are adding to the arraylist, but you never take anything out. You have to remove the second value and then add it back in.

```
temp = al.remove(i+1);
```

or

```
temp = al.get(i+1);
al.remove(i+1);
```

Since you never delete that value, the arraylist grows bigger for every new value, like an exponential function.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are not replacing the values in the relevant index of the `arraylist` ,instead what you do is increasing the size of the `arraylist` by adding more elements to it through the `al.add()` method ( here what actually happens is that the element you add, get inserted to the current `i` position while shifting the element currently at that position (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right by adding one to their indices ). 
To reset or replace the values in an arraylist you need to use the `set()` method. And in the `for loop` change it to `for(int i=0; i<al.size(); i++){...}` if you need to loop till the end of the list. Try the following code

```
public static void switchPairs(ArrayList<String> al){

        String temp=null;


        if(al.size() %2==0){        //size is even

            //loop through the entire arraylist
            for(int i=0; i<al.size(); i++){

                temp=al.get(i+1);   //get the n+1 element and assign it to a temp variable
                al.set(i, temp);                    //assign the n+1 element to the n position

            }




        }else{      //size is odd

            //loop through the entire arraylist

        }

        System.out.println("After switching pairs.");
        System.out.println(al);

    }
```